# Dynamic Accordion Menu using Jquery 1.4.2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-2, accordion

Hi i am building a jquery accordion menu using VS2008 and MVC2.

My requirement is to refresh the contents of the accordion and repopulate it when a user selects an item from a dropdownlist

For this i am using a jquery ajax call which returns data with  and  tags like below

```
<h3>
  <a href="#">Masters</a>
</h3>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" onclick="pageclick('..\TRAN\EmpMst.aspx',1)">Employee Master</a>
    </li>
    <li>
......
...
```

The first time on page load the accordion looks fine. But whenever i change the contents dynamically it looks awfull with weird CSS

[image: Accordion Before & After Dynamic Update]

here is my ajax call

```
        $('#moduleList').change(function() {
            var rootPath = '<%=Url.Content("~/")%>';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: rootPath + "Home/GetMenu/",
                data: { moduleid: $(this).val() },
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#accordion').html(result);
                    //$('#accordion').append(result);
                    $('#accordion').accordion('destroy');
                    $('#accordion').accordion({
                        fillSpace: true, collapsible: true
                    });
                },
                error: function(error) { alert(error); }
            });

        });
```

am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for your help. I finally got it right. Actually i missed a little CSS.

My IE was not showing the html with any css at all. So it was difficult to findout whether something is changed or not. Thanks to Tuan who saved my day. Once i started using Firebug it was crystal clear that a custom css was missing. Here is the updated Code just in case any one is interested.

```
    $('#moduleList').change(function() {
        var rootPath = '<%=Url.Content("~/")%>';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: rootPath + "Home/GetMenu/",
            data: { moduleid: $(this).val() },
            success: function(result) {
                $('#accordion').html(result);
                //$('#accordion').append(result);
                $('#accordion').accordion('destroy');
                $('#accordion div').addClass('navMiddle');  // I missed this at first
                $('#accordion').accordion({
                    fillSpace: true, collapsible: true
                });
            },
            error: function(error) { alert(error); }
        });

    });
```

And Here is the CSS for the Accordion menu items.

```
.navMiddle{
 position:relative;
}
.navMiddle ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    text-align:left;
    list-style:none;
}
.navMiddle ul li {
    font-size:11px;
    color:#003366;
    font-weight:normal;
    white-space:nowrap;
    position:relative;
    border-bottom:dotted 1px gray;
    padding-top:4px;
    padding-bottom:4px;
}
.navMiddle ul li:hover {
    background-color:#e5effa;
}
.navMiddle ul li a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#003366;
}
.navMiddle ul li a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#003366;
    margin-top:3px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try calling `accordion()` again after setting the html in your ajax success handler. This should re-apply the styles:

```
$("#accordion").accordion();
```

Comment: I don't think OP is using jQueryUI.

Comment: I am using jquery ui. and i tried calling $("#accordion").accordion(); on ajax success but with no luck. and i am using default styling too.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. What if you called .accordion('destroy') before .html(result)?

Comment: no matter how many times i call .accordion('destroy') both before and after assigning the html, the <a> tag sections render as plain html only

Comment: Have you used Firebug to compare the styles applied to the elements before and after?

Answer (score 1):

There might be several causes for this. Here is one possible cause:
If you use JavaScript for styling(adding CSS class etc.) your accordion menu, and that usually run on page load. 
Then call the styling function again after setting the loaded content in your success callback.

Comment: Kibria i am not using any scripts for styling. However i called $("#accordion").accordion(); from ajax success in the hope that it will re apply css and rebuild the accordion.It does not work..

Answer (score 1):

Compare the *html*(before invoking accordion()) structure of element *#accordion* with the result *html* of the ajax call. For example:

html structure before invoking accordion():

```
<h3> <a href="#">Masters</a> </h3>
<div>
 <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Employee Master</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

ajax result html structure:

```
<div> //this may destroy your CSS
   <h3> <a href="#">Masters</a> </h3>
   <div>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Employee Master</a> </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using two statement as

```
$('#accordion').accordion('destroy');
$("#accordion").accordion();
```